# Stream video using javacv to a rtsp server

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, javacv

I am using java CV for video streaming.And I captured video from web cam.But it fails when i tried to transfer the stream to the Darwin server. The code is,

```
package streamingapp;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avcodec;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.avutil.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;


public class StreamingApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
    CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame("webcam");
    FrameGrabber grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);

    grabber.setImageHeight(500);
    grabber.setImageWidth(500);
    grabber.start();

    IplImage grabbedImage = grabber.grab();
    int width = grabbedImage.width();
    int height = grabbedImage.height();

    CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();

    FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("rtsp://ipaddress:portno/testVideoStream.3gp", width, height);



    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    recorder.setFormat("rtsp");
    recorder.setFrameRate(grabber.getFrameRate());
    recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(10 * 1024 * 1024);
    recorder.start();

    int i = 0;

    while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null) {
    System.out.println("(" + i++ + ") Invio. . .");
    frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
    recorder.record(grabbedImage);
    }

    cvClearMemStorage(storage);
    recorder.stop();
    grabber.stop();
  }

}
```

Is it possible to stream video using javacv in rtsp format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.... i got the result (Darwin Server)

```java
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("rtp://ipaddress:portno/testVideoStream.sdp", width, height);

recorder.setVideoCodec(13);
recorder.setFormat("rtp");
recorder.setFrameRate(30);

//recorder.setPixelFormat(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P);
//recorder.setVideoBitrate(10 * 1024 * 1024);
recorder.start();
```